# Possible to add hook as android fetches XML-strings?

Tags: java, android, xml, oop

I'm on my first week with android and would appreciate any insight if it's possible to hook or override the default behaviour as my android application read the values from the resource-files to the shown layouts.

What I want is to over time be able to add new/updated strings `OTA` and store locally and then on launch of application load new values instead of the ones in the default /res.

Ideally i guess, would be an override of setContentView.

Files holding updates will be in same xml-format as those in /res.

(Please, no advices in other ways to do this. Just need to know if it's at all possible, without hacking the SDK)

regards,

Comment: `no advices in other ways to do this` That's not really how this site works.

Comment: @falmarri, I just want to avoid a divergating debate. Let's not start one, ok?

Comment: Well, I'm about 98% sure that it's impossible to do it the way you suggest. (Unless you count new versions of the app as OTA updates) If you're interested in knowing other ways to accomplish the same effect, there are plenty of people who would love to help.

Comment: This question will be deleted soon, new clarified post at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561956/how-to-provide-i18n-service-for-developer-and-end-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered at [How to provide i18n service for developer and end user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561956/how-to-provide-i18n-service-for-developer-and-end-user)